# Removing rows with specific name gives null observation

Tags: r

I want to remove data with specific row names. Sample data "airpollution" is as

```
 date            study          temp     death   airpollution
 2017-01-25      fi(2018/19)      2         1         22
 2017-01-26      de(2017)         5         12        28
 2017-01-27      se(2020)         7         10        32
 2017-01-28      fi(2018/19)      8         3         37
 2017-01-29      fi(2018/19)      10        5         29
```

I want to subset data with observations from fi(2018/2019).

I tried

```
  demodata<-[c("fi(2018/19)"),]
```

It gives demodata with 1 observation only. Where i am going wrong? How should i select data containing observations from "fi(2018/2019)" rows?

Comment: `res <- data[data$study == "fi(2018/19)", ]` or `res <- subset(data, study == "fi(2018/19)")`

Comment: Perfect. Solution by Darren helps. Thank you. Much appreciated